# Partition a set in Haskell

Tags: haskell, set, partition

I'm trying to write a Haskell program that could return the partition set of a user defined set. The partition of a set S is defined as a set of nonempty, pairwise disjoint subsets of S whose union is S.  So, `[1,2,3]` returns `[[[2],[3,1]],[[2,1],[3]],[[3,2,1]],[[1],[3,2]],[[1],[2],[3]]]`.  I think I can utilize a different program I wrote a while ago that finds the cartesian product from two sets. So, `[1,2,3] ['a', 'b']` returns `[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'a'),(3,'b')]`. However, I'm not sure quite how.  I think it would require recursion though, if this can even be adapted properly.  Here is the subset code:

```
type Set a = [a]

isElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
isElement x [] = False
isElement x (y:ys) = if(x==y) then True else isElement x ys

subset :: Eq a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool
subset [] xs = True
subset (y:ys) xs = if(isElement y xs == True)
                  then do subset ys xs
                  else do False
```

Comment: Recursively. If you can partition `X`, how can you partition `X ∪ {a}`?

Comment: Minor style comment: the `if`s you posted seem to be a convoluted way to write, respectively, 1) `x==y || isElement x ys` and 2) `isElement y xs && subset ys xs`. There's no need of `do` here, and `== True` is always redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is that in order to find all partitions of set *X* ∪ {*x*},  we find parritions of *X* first. Then add `x` to each of them in every possible way (that is, add `x` to the first element of a partition, add `x` to the second element etc) and take a union of the result.

Here's a rather straightforward implementation:

```
partitions :: [a] -> [[[a]]]
partitions [] = [[]]
partitions (x:xs) = expand x $ partitions xs where

    expand :: a -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
    expand x ys = concatMap (extend x) ys

    extend :: a -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
    extend x [] = [[[x]]]
    extend x (y:ys) = ((x:y):ys) : map (y:) (extend x ys)
```

Demo: 
https://ideone.com/ClYOoQ

Comment: You can also define `partitions` as `partitions = foldr expand [[]]`

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode for one recursive algorithm:

```
If |S| = 1
  Return ∅
Otherwise
  For each nonempty proper subset X ⊂ S
    Let Y = S - X
    Add {X, Y} to R
    For each Z in {partitionSet(X)}
      Add Z ∪ {Y} to R.
  Return R
```

Since “adding” elements to a list isn’t a very functional idiom, you would want to do those steps with a concatMap or a list comprehension.  You might also build R as an accumulating parameter to a tail-recursive function, or as a union of the return values of each step.  The proper subsets function is in the Haskell standard library as `Data.List.subsequences`.

If you have a total ordering on all proper subsets of S, you can use symmetry-breaking to add only partitions that are unique up to permutation.  That is, if X > Y, you could add only {X,Y} and not {Y,X}, and only {X,Y,Z} and not {Y,X,Z}.  Be careful that you still sub-partition every set in your partition exactly once!

This finds only partition sets of S, if ⋃Z = X and X ∪ Y = S, the union of all sets in Z and Y is S, it returns only sets of nonempty proper subsets of S, and every partition and subpartition is a set difference, hence pairwise disjoint.

Any partition set of cardinality two has the form {X, S-X}, and the algorithm finds it because it tries every possible X.  Any partition set of cardinality *i*>2 has the form {a_1, a_2, ..., a_i}, where {a_1, a_2} is a partition set of {a_1 ⋃ a_2} and {{a_1 ⋃ a_2}, ..., a_i} is a partition set of cardinality *i*-1, and will be found when subpartitioning the parent node of the search tree.  Therefore, by induction, the algorithm finds all partition sets of S.

Comment: Yeah, I generally don’t write complete solutions of questions that look like homework problems, but I do give hints.

Comment: Would you prefer if I deleted that comment? I added it since (1) this was a cool idea, (2) there is already a much simpler solution with the other posted answer and (3) it wasn't immediately clear to me what you meant.

Comment: @Alec It’s really up to you.

Comment: Given that two strangers agreed with you, I've deleted the comment. :)

Comment: @Alec Well, six strangers upvoted a different complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, I was playing again with set partitions and haskell. Even though it might be not the fastest and nicest solution it does the job. I found out that using Data.List and the List Monad greatly reduces the amount of code and extents the readability.

Asking myself if there is a neat way to replace `foldl` by `foldr`?

Anyway, here is my solution:

```
module Main where

import Data.List

main :: IO ()
main = print $ allPart 5

insertFront :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
insertFront k (h:t) = [k:h]++t
insertFront k _ = [[k]]

add :: Integer -> [[Integer]] -> [[[Integer]]]
add k part=zipWith (++) (inits part) (map (insertFront k) (tails part))

allPart k = foldl (>>=) [[]] [add i | i<-[1..k]]
```

I'm also wondering if there is some very short substitute for insertFront using some of the haskell libraries.